# Jupyterlab extension install for Plotly 4.9.0 fails

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, plotly-python

I'm trying to install Plotly for use within a Jupyter Lab environment using the instructions from Plotly's web site [Instructions](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/). I'm installing on top of a fresh Anaconda 64-bit install on a Windows 10 OS. The following install commands all worked correctly

```
conda install -c plotly plotly=4.9.0
conda install "notebook>=5.3" "ipywidgets>=7.2"
conda install jupyterlab "ipywidgets=7.5"
```

I also installed nodejs using:

```
conda install nodejs
```

But when it comes time to do the Jupyter Lab specific stuff then this fails

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0
An error occured.
ValueError: "jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0" is not a valid npm package
See the log file for details:  C:\Users\tj\AppData\Local\Temp\jupyterlab-debug-cm_yk8nr.log
```

The log file says the following:

```
Node v10.13.0

Yarn configuration loaded.
> C:\Users\tj\Anaconda3\npm.CMD pack jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/jupyterlab-plotly failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for jupyterlab-plotly@4.9.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tj\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-25T14_44_35_633Z-debug.log
```

So all indications to me are that it thinks it can't find the nodejs package called jupyterlab-plotly. If I go to the NPM site I can find the package [jupyterlab-plotly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jupyterlab-plotly) which indicates it's version 4.9.0.

It's not clear to me where I've gone wrong. Has anyone successfully followed these steps and gotten plotly to work properly in a Jupyter Lab environement?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this process again with the latest plotly 4.10 and had the same issue. However, I just now got it all to work. The difference is that with all previous failed attempts I was operating while within our corporate network. It worked when I was only attached via our VPN. So there's some sort of firewall difference between the two that I will attempt to sort out.